# Connecting groups (Phone validator)

Tags: regex

I need to make phone validator where:

- 1st character is `+ ( or digit`
- there can not be `() / . -` characters next to each other
- only `digits  () / . - or space` are allowed
- length doesn't matter

Example

```
123-431-123/23 - true
+312-31-32-53 - true
000-132+23 false
000()312 false
122--231 false
```

Here is my pattern, almost works but allows letters and other characters out of set :/

```
^[+( 0-9]{1}([0-9 .\/()-])((?:(?![.\/()-]{2}).)*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/n6Tro_pswo1iPCDW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give this regex a try:

```
^[+(0-9](?:[0-9 ]+[()/.-])*[0-9 ]+$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jR3lW4).

The group `(?:[0-9 ]+[()/.-])*` is what is preventing the special characters you mentioned to occur in a row, and I'm not using the `.` wildcard, so no other characters will be matched.

Answer (score 1):

This meets your requirements, and also recognizes Americanized phone numbers, such as `(123) 456-7890`.

`^(?:[+(])?(\d+)(?:\))?(?:[ -/])?(\d+)(?:[ -/])?(\d+)(?:[ -/])?(\d*)$`

Although it doesn't work in debuggex, here's its image:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It does work on regexplanet:  http://fiddle.re/53ktv  (press Java)

Working example: Top through regex:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java PhoneNumberValidatorXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class PhoneNumberValidatorXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

      String sOptionalSpaceDashSlash = "(?:[ -/])?";
      String sOneOrMoreDigitsCAPTURED = "(\\d+)";

      String sREPhone = "" +
         "^(?:[+(])?" +         //+ or (             [start of line, then optional]
         sOneOrMoreDigitsCAPTURED +
         "(?:\\))?" +           //Closing )          [optional]
         sOptionalSpaceDashSlash +
         sOneOrMoreDigitsCAPTURED +
         sOptionalSpaceDashSlash +
         sOneOrMoreDigitsCAPTURED +
         sOptionalSpaceDashSlash +
         "(\\d*)$";             //one-or-more digits [optional, then end of line]

         //Equivalent to:
         //String sREPhone = "" +
         //   "^(?:[+(])?" +      //+ or (             [start of line, then optional]
         //   "(\\d+)" +          //one-or-more digits CAPTURED
         //   "(?:\\))?" +        //Closing )          [optional]
         //   "(?:[ -/])?" +      //- or / or SPACE    [optional]
         //   "(\\d+)" +          //one-or-more digits CAPTURED
         //   "(?:[ -/])?" +      //- or / or SPACE    [optional]
         //   "(\\d+)" +          //one-or-more digits CAPTURED
         //   "(?:[ -/])?" +      //- or / or SPACE    [optional]
         //   "(\\d*)$";          //one-or-more digits CAPTURED [optional, then end of line]
```

Bottom half, with tests and logic:

```
      //Create matcher with unused string, so it can be reused in test(m,s)
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sREPhone).matcher("");

      test(m, "123-431-123/23");  //true
      test(m, "+312-31-32-53");   //true
      test(m, "(123) 456-7890");  //true
      test(m, "000-132+23");      //false
      test(m, "000()312");        //false
      test(m, "122--231");        //false
   }
   private static final void test(Matcher m_m, String s_toTest)  {
      m_m.reset(s_toTest);
      System.out.println(s_toTest + "  -->  " + m_m.matches());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java PhoneNumberValidatorXmpl
123-431-123/23  -->  true
+312-31-32-53  -->  true
(123) 456-7890  -->  true
000-132+23  -->  false
000()312  -->  false
122--231  -->  false
```